# How to trim the spaces in url with parameters in jsp?

Tags: jsp, url, trim

In my application, When hyperlink clicked by the end user, The javascript function will get executed. and it generates request. But with parameters, the url is generating with space between parameters.

How to trim the space in the url?
Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL must not contain a literal space. You should encode the url using built in javascript function [encodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var uri="my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
    document.write(encodeURI(uri)+ "<br />");

</script>
```

Or  Better  use [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) as you want to encode a URL parameter.
Hope this  helps.

Comment: Hi Muse, The parameter values will be coming dynamically.. so that the space is coming.. not static values as you have mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should check your JavaScript code that generates such url with space between parameters. That is not correct. So instead of trying to trim the url, you should modify your javascript code that generates the url.

Comment: Hi Japan, sometimes it is working fine.. But some times it is generating space. So to avoid that situations i want to trim the spaces..

Comment: Can you show your javascript code here that is causing the problem while generating the url?